# How to tell the compiler the variant of the enum I'm returning always has no lifetime?

Tags: enums, rust, borrow-checker

The below code won't compile because the compiler thinks I shouldn't assign to `t1` since it is borrowed, but in reality the function `always_returns_no_lifetime` will always be returning a variant of the enum that actually doesn't have an lifetime, so it is okay for me to modify `t1`. How can I get the compiler to understand this or how should I reorganize my code to make this error not happen?

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Types<'a> {
    NoLifetime(i32),
    AlsoNoLifetime(i32),
    AlsoAlsoNoLifetime(i32),
    HasLifetime(&'a str)
}

fn always_returns_no_lifetime<'a>(some_type: &'a Types) -> Types<'a> {
    match *some_type {
        Types::HasLifetime(text) => panic!("I only return the type that has no lifetime"),
        _ => some_type.clone()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut t1 = Types::NoLifetime(20);

    let copy = always_returns_no_lifetime(&t1);

    t1 = Types::NoLifetime(30);

}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5a5419800bcc138ea3b735c671c8dd0d&version=stable)

The error is:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `t1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:23:5
   |
21 |     let copy = always_returns_no_lifetime(&t1);
   |                                            -- borrow of `t1` occurs here
22 |     
23 |     t1 = Types::NoLifetime(30);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `t1` occurs here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type of your function is wrong. If the return value is guaranteed not to have any lifetime, then it should be marked as such, and not tied down to an arbitrary lifetime:

```
fn always_returns_no_lifetime(...) -> Types<'static>;
```

With this change, you actually no longer need any *input* lifetime either, since they are only useful to tie the input and output, leading the following signature:

```
fn always_returns_no_lifetime(some_type: &Types) -> Types<'static>;
```

Unfortunately, this means that `clone` is now out of the table, as it clones the lifetime, so the implementation has to change too:

```
fn always_returns_no_lifetime(some_type: &Types) -> Types<'static> {
    match *some_type {
        Types::HasLifetime(_)
            => panic!("I only return values that have no lifetime"),
        Types::NoLifetime(i) => Types::NoLifetime(i),
        Types::AlsoNoLifetime(i) => Types::AlsoNoLifetime(i),
        Types::AlsoAlsoNoLifetime(i) => Types::AlsoAlsoNoLifetime(i),
    }
}
```

The benefit of this implementation can be demonstrated in the following example:

```
fn tie<'a>(text: &'a str) -> Types<'a> {
    if text[0] == 'a' {
        Types::HasLifetime(text)
    } else {
        Types::NoLifetime(0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let no_lifetime = {
        let string = String::from("Hello, world");
        let has_lifetime = tie(&*string);
        always_returns_no_lifetime(&has_lifetime)
    };

    //  Requires deriving Debug, all structs really should...
    println!("{:?}", no_lifetime);
}
```

If you preserve the lifetime when you don't need it, you cannot compile this example, it's an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand what you are trying to show in the second example. I see what you did with the scopes at the bottom, but what is the tie function supposed to be showing?

Comment: @Keatinge: The `tie` function is creating a `Types<'a>` which ties the value to the lifetime of its input (note it has the same lifetime). This is what results in `has_lifetime` having the same lifetime as the `string` variable. If you try to return `has_lifetime` from the block, the compiler will warn that you cannot, as the `string` is destroyed at the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of applying the `'a` lifetime parameter on the *reference*, apply it on `Types`, as you already did with the return type. The lifetime on the reference is not important when you call `.clone()` on it.

```
fn always_returns_no_lifetime<'a>(some_type: &Types<'a>) -> Types<'a> {
    match *some_type {
        Types::HasLifetime(text) => panic!("I only return the type that has no lifetime"),
        _ => some_type.clone()
    }
}
```